# SQL Server - Previous day data retrieval where

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2012-express

I am retrieving data from a view for a dashboard and I need some help with my query to retrieve yesterday's data where the following conditions meet:

When 'Monday' retrieve JUST friday's data.
When 'Tuesday' retrieve data from Saturday until Monday, 
When 'other days' JUST retrieve previous day,

But there is another condition:
Exclude 'previous day' data WHERE  "DESP...' is empty. (as this will skew the percentages)

This is what I have so far:

```
SELECT CORD_DocumentCode
,OpenDate
,datedue
,DESP_PostedDate
,COUNT(CORD_DocumentCode) AS Order_Count
,SUM(CASE WHEN InFullAndOneTime = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Difot_count
,SUM(CASE WHEN InFullAndOneTime = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) * 1.0 /COUNT(CORD_DocumentCode) AS DIFOT
FROM DIFOTIS_View
WHERE (OpenDate >= CASE WHEN DATENAME(dw, CONVERT(CHAR(8), GETDATE(), 112)) LIKE 'Monday' THEN CONVERT(CHAR(8), DATEADD(dd, - 2, GETDATE()), 112) 
                         WHEN DATENAME(dw, CONVERT(CHAR(8), GETDATE(), 112)) LIKE 'Tuesday' THEN CONVERT(CHAR(8), DATEADD(dd, - 3, GETDATE()), 112) ELSE CONVERT(CHAR(8), 
                         DATEADD(dd, - 1, GETDATE()), 112) END) --AND) (OpenDate < CONVERT(CHAR(8), GETDATE(), 112)) 


Group by OpenDate,CORD_DocumentCode, datedue, DESP_PostedDate
order by OpenDate
```

This will show you yesterday's data as today is 'Wednesday' and the result is 
15.4 % (or 4/26) whereas I would like it to show 80% (or 4 / 5)

I have tried adding

```
((Datediff(day,Opendate,getdate())=1) and DESP_PostedDate is not null)
```

but it shows then only data from the 21Oct.

What do you suggest I should do?
Please find below Data from friday for your perusal.

All help is appreciated. Thanks

Eric

```
CORD_DocumentCode      OpenDate     datedue     DESP_PostedDate Order_Count Difot_count DIFOT
CASW92195               2014-10-19  2014-10-19  2014-10-20  1   1   1.000000000000
CASW92196               2014-10-19  2014-10-19  2014-10-20  1   1   1.000000000000
CASW92197               2014-10-19  2014-10-19  2014-10-20  1   1   1.000000000000
CASW92198               2014-10-19  2014-10-19  2014-10-20  1   1   1.000000000000
CASW92199               2014-10-19  2014-10-19  2014-10-20  1   1   1.000000000000
CASW92200               2014-10-19  2014-10-19  NULL        1   0   0.000000000000
CASW92201               2014-10-20  2014-10-20  2014-10-20  1   1   1.000000000000
CASW92202               2014-10-20  2014-10-20  2014-10-20  1   1   1.000000000000
CASW92203               2014-10-20  2014-10-20  2014-10-21  1   1   1.000000000000
CASW92204               2014-10-20  2014-10-20  2014-10-21  1   1   1.000000000000
CASW92205               2014-10-20  2014-10-20  2014-10-21  1   1   1.000000000000
CASW92206               2014-10-20  2014-10-20  2014-10-21  1   1   1.000000000000
CORD37188               2014-10-20  2014-10-20  NULL        1   0   0.000000000000
CORD37189               2014-10-20  2014-10-20  2014-10-20  1   0   0.000000000000
CORD37190               2014-10-20  2014-10-20  2014-10-20  1   0   0.000000000000
CORD37191               2014-10-20  2014-10-20  2014-10-21  1   0   0.000000000000
CORD37192               2014-10-20  2014-10-20  2014-10-20  1   0   0.000000000000
CORD37193               2014-10-20  2014-10-20  2014-10-20  1   0   0.000000000000
CORD37195               2014-10-20  2014-10-20  2014-10-20  1   0   0.000000000000
CORD37196               2014-10-20  2014-10-20  2014-10-20  1   0   0.000000000000
CORD37197               2014-10-20  2014-10-20  2014-10-21  1   0   0.000000000000
CORD37198               2014-10-20  2014-10-20  2014-10-21  1   0   0.000000000000
CORD37199               2014-10-20  2014-10-20  2014-10-20  1   0   0.000000000000
CORD37200               2014-10-20  2014-10-20  NULL        1   0   0.000000000000
CORD37211               2014-10-20  2014-10-20  2014-10-21  1   1   1.000000000000
CORD37216               2014-10-20  2014-10-20  2014-10-21  1   1   1.000000000000
CASW92207               2014-10-21  2014-10-21  2014-10-21  1   1   1.000000000000
CASW92208               2014-10-21  2014-10-21  2014-10-21  1   1   1.000000000000
CASW92209               2014-10-21  2014-10-21  2014-10-21  1   1   1.000000000000
CASW92210               2014-10-21  2014-10-21  NULL        1   0   0.000000000000
CASW92211               2014-10-21  2014-10-21  NULL        1   0   0.000000000000
CASW92212               2014-10-21  2014-10-21  NULL        1   0   0.000000000000
CASW92213               2014-10-21  2014-10-21  NULL        1   0   0.000000000000
CORD37218               2014-10-21  2014-10-21  2014-10-21  1   1   1.000000000000
CORD37220               2014-10-21  2014-10-20  2014-10-21  1   0   0.000000000000
CORD37221               2014-10-21  2014-10-21  NULL        1   0   0.000000000000
CORD37222               2014-10-21  2014-10-21  NULL        1   0   0.000000000000
CORD37225               2014-10-21  2014-10-21  NULL        1   0   0.000000000000
CORD37227               2014-10-21  2014-10-21  NULL        1   0   0.000000000000
CORD37228               2014-10-21  2014-10-21  NULL        1   0   0.000000000000
CORD37229               2014-10-21  2014-10-21  NULL        1   0   0.000000000000
CORD37230               2014-10-21  2014-10-21  NULL        1   0   0.000000000000
CORD37231               2014-10-21  2014-10-21  NULL        1   0   0.000000000000
CORD37232               2014-10-21  2014-10-21  NULL        1   0   0.000000000000
CORD37233               2014-10-21  2014-10-21  NULL        1   0   0.000000000000
CORD37234               2014-10-21  2014-10-21  NULL        1   0   0.000000000000
CORD37235               2014-10-21  2014-10-21  NULL        1   0   0.000000000000
CORD37236               2014-10-21  2014-10-21  NULL        1   0   0.000000000000
CORD37237               2014-10-21  2014-10-21  NULL        1   0   0.000000000000
CORD37238               2014-10-21  2014-10-21  NULL        1   0   0.000000000000
CORD37239               2014-10-21  2014-10-21  NULL        1   0   0.000000000000
CORD37241               2014-10-21  2014-10-21  NULL        1   0   0.000000000000
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It took me a while but I got this sorted out with the help of Shiv. from another forum.
I am posting the answer here for future reference.

```
/*Main Query */
declare @ReportDate datetime = getdate()


SELECT    COUNT(CORD_DocumentCode) as [count], SUM(CASE WHEN InFullAndOneTime = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Difot_count, 
                         SUM(CASE WHEN InFullAndOneTime = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) * 1.0 / COUNT(CORD_DocumentCode) AS DIFOT
FROM            DIFOTIS_View
WHERE  cast(datepart(dw,OpenDate) as varchar) in       
(SELECT * FROM dbo.CSVToTable(Case
when datepart(dw,@ReportDate) =7 and DESP_PostedDate is NOT null then '6' 
when datepart(dw,@ReportDate) =6 and DESP_PostedDate is NOT null then '5'  
when datepart(dw,@ReportDate) =5 and DESP_PostedDate is NOT null then '4'  
when datepart(dw,@ReportDate) =4 and DESP_PostedDate is NOT null then '3'  
when datepart(dw,@ReportDate) =2 and DESP_PostedDate is NOT null then '6'  
when datepart(dw,@ReportDate) =3 and DESP_PostedDate is NOT null then '7,1,2'
when datepart(dw,@ReportDate) =1 and DESP_PostedDate is NOT null then '7' Else NULL END)) and opendate>=DATEADD(day, -7,@ReportDate)

/* Function Creation*/ 
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[CSVToTable] (@InStr VARCHAR(MAX))
RETURNS @TempTab TABLE
   (id int not null)
AS
BEGIN
    ;-- Ensure input ends with comma
    SET @InStr = REPLACE(@InStr + ',', ',,', ',')
    DECLARE @SP INT
DECLARE @VALUE VARCHAR(1000)
WHILE PATINDEX('%,%', @INSTR ) <> 0 
BEGIN
   SELECT  @SP = PATINDEX('%,%',@INSTR)
   SELECT  @VALUE = LEFT(@INSTR , @SP - 1)
   SELECT  @INSTR = STUFF(@INSTR, 1, @SP, '')
   INSERT INTO @TempTab(id) VALUES (@VALUE)
END
    RETURN
END
GO
```

Cheers
H